# Common-Lisp: binding formal parameters, exactly what is passed?

Tags: common-lisp, symbols

Suppose we have a symbol, with a symbol value and a function value and a property list and let us call it `q`.  Suppose also that we have a function `f` with formal parameter `v`, e.g. `(f (v) ... )` and call the function like `(f q)`.

My question is: what is exactly passed to `v`?  Are

1. the value of `q`;
2. the function value of `q`;
3. property list of `q`,

passed to the formal parameter `v`?

If they are all passed to `v`, then I am puzzled by the fact that we really need the functions `funcall` and `apply`.  If `v` would really have both the value and the function value, then it can surely itself decide that when we write `(v 3)`, then it must use the function value of `v` instead of `(funcall v 3)`.    And when we use `(setq v 3)` then it must use the value of `v`.

What is exactly passed to `v` and why `v` is not a symbol, but just a "parameter" or "variable", is an enigma to me.  But I believe that it was in Lisp 1.5 really a symbol.  But in common Lisp, there seems to be some
room to confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of variable `q` is passed.

`(f q)` is an **evaluated** form, in this case the name `q` is interpreted as a variable.

If you want to acces the function value or property list of the name `q` in function `f`, you need to quote the name and say `'q`. By doing this, you're referring to the *global registry* of function values and property list values, instead of the *local information* passed inside function `f`.

*Only* the value of variable `q` is passed inside function `f`.

Comment: I find this information very helpful.  It is sometimes very confusing in the literature.  I saw in the literature very distinct opinions and explanations about this all.  I sometimes wonder if this is not caused by the long history of lisp.  The confusing about symbols versus variables, passing functions to functions, the terminology about the bindings is a source of long standing confusion.

Answer (score 6):

If you have

```
(f q)
```

it means *call the function `f` with the value of `q`*.

1. Lisp sees that `f` is a function, so the whole `(f q)` is a function form.
2. Lisp evaluates `q` to its value.
3. Lisp calls `f` with one value.
4. Lisp binds the local variable `v` to the passed value
5. Lisp executes the body of the function `f`
   ...

`v` is in the source code a symbol, but it denotes a variable. In compiled code the symbol is gone. Since Common Lisp uses lexical bindings, variables are now lexical references.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're quoting it, you're passing the symbol `q`not any of its values; those values can be accessed within `f` by using `(symbol-value v)` or `(symbol-function v)`.

The reason you need `funcall` is because Common Lisp uses the function value of a symbol when it appears at the head of a list to evaluate. So if you write

```
(v 3)
```

it will call the function value of the symbol `v`. But the value that was passed to `f` is in the value of `v`, not the function value. But when you write

```
(funcall v 3)
```

`v` is in the argument list, so it's evaluated to get its value. That value is the symbol `q`, and when you try to call a symbol, `funcall` looks up its function value, so it's equivalent in this case to

```
(funcall (symbol-function v) 3)
```